# Auto-start MarkLogic on OSX

Tags: macos, marklogic

The OSX version of MarkLogic installs a preference pane in System Preferences, but it doesn't provide an option to automatically start MarkLogic whenever you log in.

[Another MarkLogic developer created a launchd config](http://markmail.org/message/ryvwjonio6sfc6pj) to start it, but I couldn't get it to work (in OSX 10.10). Is there another way to automate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "MarkLogic"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        set toggle to button 1 of group 1 of window 1
        if title of toggle is "Start MarkLogic Server" then
            click toggle
        end if
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    quit
end tell
```

1. Save this script as an application (not a .scpt script file).
2. Open System Preferences > Users & Groups and select the user for which you
   would like MarkLogic to start automatically, then select Login Items
   tab on the right.
3. Click the plus button and navigate to the location
   of the saved application, and click Add.

**OSX 10.11 El Capitan Update**

In 10.11, one of the item indexes in MarkLogic's Preference Pane is not consistently reliable. This script will achieve the same goal, and should be backward compatible with previous OSX versions. Follow steps 1-3 above with this script:

```
do shell script "~/Library/StartupItems/MarkLogic/MarkLogic start"
```